# Sequential search and freeing array using C

Tags: c

So I'm trying to use sequential search to check how many times a string comes up within my array. Within my program I ask the user to select which file they wish to open and be process.

```
void search(char **table, int **frequency, int wordSize)
{
//  Local Declaration
int i, j;
int count = 1;
char target[25];

// Statement
for(i = 0; i < wordSize; i++)
{
    if(table[i] != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(target, table[i]);
        for(j = i + 1; j < wordSize; j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(target, table[j]) == 0 && target != table[i])
            {
                count++;
                free(table[j]);
                table[j] = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    count = 1;
}

return;
}
```

So out of the two files, one of them open and process without any problems, but when I try opening the second file it crashes. I'm trying to understand what's going on that's making my program crash, because both files just contains strings and none of the strings surpasses 24 characters.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(table[j] != NULL && strcmp(target, table[j]) == 0 && target != table[i])
```

You could be accessing the `table` variable which you have `NULL`ed in a prev iteration.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't catch that one. I really appreciate the quick reply and the help.